# Finding largest areas in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, max, area

I'm writing a function where I go through a dictionary. The dictionary contains artists as keys and their paintings as values. I need to find the painting in a dictionary that has the largest area and if there are two that have equal area they should be returned as a list of tuples.

Example Dictionary:

```
{
        'A, Jr.':[("One",1400,10,20.5,"oil paint","Austria"),("Three",1400,100.0,100.0,"oil paint","France"),("Twenty",1410,50.0,200.0,"oil paint","France")],
        'X':[("Eight",1460, 100.0, 20.0, "oil paint","France"),("Six",1465,10.0, 23.0, "oil paint", "France"),("Ten",1465,12.0,15.0,"oil paint","Austria"),("Thirty",1466,30.0,30.0,"watercolor","Germany")],   
        'M':[("One, Two", 1500, 10.0, 10.0, "panel","Germany")]
        }
```

Basically the four digit number is the year that the painting or work of art was created and the next two numbers are the length and width. I need to return the values that have the largest area when multiplying the lengths and widths. So for the above dictionary the function find_largest should return

```
find_largest(dictionary2())

[('A, Jr.', 'Three'), ('A, Jr.', 'Twenty')]
```

Since 100 * 100 = 10,000 for the "Three" painting and 50 * 200 = 10,000 for the "Twenty" painting they are both returned as tuples within a list.

Does anyone have advice on how to do this? I have started code below but I don't think its the right approach for this.

```
def find_largest(dictionary):
    matches = {}
    for key, the_list in db.items():
        for record in the_list:
            value = record[4]
            if dictionary in record:
                if key in matches:
                    max(the_list)
                    max(lst, key=lambda tupl: tupl[2]*tupl[3])
                    matches[key].append(record)
                else:
                    matches[key] = [record]
    return matches
```

This is basically my code from an earlier function with a few significant changes. This basic framework has worked for a few of my goals. I added max(matches) but I realize this isn't doing much unless the function multiplies the lengths and widths and then looks for the max. If anyone has advice it would be helpful

Comment: You can pass `max` a `key` parameter: `max(lst, key=lambda tupl: tupl[2]*tupl[3])` would get you the tuple with largest area from one list in your dict.

Comment: Thanks for the advice should I put this in place of max(matches)?

Comment: this would be more suited for `max(the_list)` in that code, but max will generally return only one item, even if multiple items share the max value

Comment: Thanks I added your suggestions I'll test and see what the function does now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be easier to just keep track of your current max instead

```
data = {
        'A, Jr.':[("One",1400,10,20.5,"oil paint","Austria"),("Three",1400,100.0,100.0,"oil paint","France"),("Twenty",1410,50.0,200.0,"oil paint","France")],
        'X':[("Eight",1460, 100.0, 20.0, "oil paint","France"),("Six",1465,10.0, 23.0, "oil paint", "France"),("Ten",1465,12.0,15.0,"oil paint","Austria"),("Thirty",1466,30.0,30.0,"watercolor","Germany")],   
        'M':[("One, Two", 1500, 10.0, 10.0, "panel","Germany")]
        }

def find_largest(d):
    matches = []
    max_value = 0
    for key in d:
        for record in d[key]:
            value = record[2] * record[3]
            if value > max_value:
                matches = [(key, record[0])]
                max_value = value
            elif value == max_value:
                matches.append((key, record[0]))
    return matches

# Output
>>> find_largest(data)
[('A, Jr.', 'Three'), ('A, Jr.', 'Twenty')]
```

Comment: Thanks this solution is perfect. Do you know how I could have this function return None if matches is empty at the end instead of having it return the empty list or '[]'?

Comment: I tried elif len(matches) == 0:
                matches = None but this doesnt work

Comment: The function will only ever return None  if dictionary is empty. So you can check for that before you start the for-loop `if not d: return`. Or initially set `matches = None`. Or if you don't like the idea of setting it to None just add a check for the return `if matches: return matches`

Comment: Thanks adding if not d: return before the loop worked